# Google Earth Engine, get a list of unique values in a list

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a list of unique values in a ee.List() object. For example:

input=ee.List([1,1,1,4,4,5,6,6])
output=[1,4,5,6]

I originally thought I could use the ee.List.distinct() function, but this does not appear to be an actual valid function. Since then I've tried a variety of different approaches including a variation of the solution to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024791/using-gee-code-editor-to-create-unique-values-list-from-existing-list-pulled-fro) to no avail.

My current approach involves an iterator function that appends newly encountered values to a new "unique values" list, however it just seems to be recognizing every value as unique and outputting the original list.

Here is my code:

```
var test_list=ee.List([1,1,1,4,5,6,6])
var iterlist=ee.List([])

function unique_list(inputItem, distinct_values){
  distinct_values=ee.List(distinct_values);
  var number=ee.Number(inputItem);
  if(distinct_values.contains(number)===true){
    distinct_values=distinct_values
  }
  else{
    distinct_values=distinct_values.add(number)
  }
  return distinct_values;
}

var result=test_list.iterate(unique_list, iterlist)
print('unique list is', result)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an `ee.List.distinct()` method.

```
ee.List([1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6]).distinct()
```